# Kubernetes: Cannot access resources in cert-manager namespace from default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, cert-manager

I am trying to learn how Kubernetes works, so I have made my own `K3S` cluster using the [quickstart guide](https://docs.k3s.io/quick-start).

Then I installed Cert Manager using the [guide for Helm](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/).

I want to use Let's Encrypt certificates for my cluster and validate them using the `dns01` webhook with my DNS provider Simply.com.

This can be done by using a webhook found here:

https://github.com/RunnerM/simply-dns-webhook

Currently I am testing if I can a certificate from Let's Encrypt by using their staging server.

I made the Yaml file `letsencrypt-staging.yaml` with the following content for `ClusterIssuer`:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: default
spec:
  acme:
    email: me@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging-key
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        webhook:
          groupName: com.github.runnerm.cert-manager-simply-webhook
          solverName: simply-dns-solver
          config:
            secretName: simply-credentials # notice the name
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'cluster.example.com'
        - '*.cluster.example.com'
```

My configuration file is basically a verbatim copy-paste from the example found at RunnerM GitHub page.

In order to issue a certificate I created a Yaml file called `certificate-test.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: test-certificate
spec:
  dnsNames:
  - test.cluster.example.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-staging
    kind: ClusterIssuer

  secretName: test-certificate-tls
```

I should then be able to get a certificate issued by using the following to commands:

```bash
kubectl apply -f letsencrypt-staging.yaml
kubectl apply -f certificate-test.yaml
```

However I am not getting a certificate issued.

When running `kubectl describe challenge test-certificate-1-1965387138-1295925723` i get the following error message:

```
...
Status:
  Presented:   false
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      secrets "simply-credentials" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:my-simply-dns-webhook" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "cert-manager"
  State:       pending
E
...
```

I get that the Simply DNS webhook `my-simply-dns-webhook` is running in the `default` namespace and the Simply DNS credentials is stored in the `cert-manager` namespace.

So how do I permit the Simply DNS webhook to access resources in the cert-manager namespace?

**Additional information**

Running the command `kubectl get clusterrolebindings` gives amongst other the following informations:

```
my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access                    ClusterRole/my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access                    76s
simply-dns-webhook:challenge-management                ClusterRole/simply-dns-webhook:challenge-management                76s
my-simply-dns-webhook:domain-solver                    ClusterRole/my-simply-dns-webhook:domain-solver                    76s
my-simply-dns-webhook:flow-control                     ClusterRole/my-simply-dns-webhook:flow-control                     76s
my-simply-dns-webhook:auth-delegator                   ClusterRole/system:auth-delegator                                  76s
```

Output from `kubectl get clusterrole my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access` gives the following result:

```
Name:         my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access
Labels:       app=simply-dns-webhook
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              chart=simply-dns-webhook-1.5.4
              heritage=Helm
              release=my-simply-dns-webhook
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-simply-dns-webhook
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  secrets.*  []                 []              [get]
```

And the command `kubectl describe clusterrolebindings my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access` gives the output:

```
Name:         my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access
Labels:       app=simply-dns-webhook
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              chart=simply-dns-webhook-1.5.4
              heritage=Helm
              release=my-simply-dns-webhook
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-simply-dns-webhook
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  my-simply-dns-webhook:secret-access
Subjects:
  Kind            Name                   Namespace
  ----            ----                   ---------
  ServiceAccount  my-simply-dns-webhook  cert-manager
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you need to grant the `my-simply-dns-webhook` ServiceAccount permissions to read secrets in the `cert-manager` namespace. That's a pretty typical RBAC issue (which the kubernetes documentation covers in a good level of detail).

Comment: It looks like the [simply-dns-webhook helm chart](https://github.com/RunnerM/simply-dns-webhook#helm-chart) sets up the RBAC for you already.

Comment: I have added additional information to question if that can clue you into what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simply-dns-webhook helm chart is buggy.

It creates a ServiceAccount named `simply-dns-webhook` in the `default` namespace (or whatever namespace you pass to `helm install`'s `-n` argument), but the `simply-dns-webhook:secret-access` ClusterRoleBinding specifies:

```
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: simply-dns-webhook:secret-access
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: simply-dns-webhook
  namespace: cert-manager
```

That's never going to match.

It might work if you deploy everything into the `cert-manager` namespace:

```
helm install -n cert-manager simply-dns-webhook simply-dns-webhook/simply-dns-webhook
```

Comment: That certainly helped. Last two entries from `kubectl get events` now says `Challenge scheduled for processing` and then `Presented challenge using DNS-01 challenge mechanism`. I guess I just have to be a little bit patient from here, since I do not see a DNS record beginning with `_well-known.*` in my Simply DNS control panel? :-)

Comment: Hm... I guess there are more issues with the webhook provider, because cert-manager never try to make a connection to my DNS provider. But that is outside the scope of this question.